# MySQL Group By zip code

Tags: mysql, group-by, zipcode

I have a table that holds subscription information.  Some of the mailing zip codes are five digits, while some are 9 (55025 vs. 55025-4056).  I want to run a query to count the total subscriptions in each zip code, but need to group the 9 digit ones with the 5 digit ones where they match.

```
SELECT zip, COUNT(id) AS total FROM subscriptions WHERE status = 'A' GROUP BY zip
```

But obviously it reads 55025 and 55025-4056 as two different zip codes.  If 55025 has 100 records and 55025-4056 has 10 records, I would like for the result to show 55025 = 110 records.  How can I perform this query to group by the first 5 digits of the zip code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT LEFT(zip,5) zip, COUNT(id) AS total
FROM subscriptions WHERE status = 'A'
GROUP BY LEFT(zip,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT zip, COUNT(id) AS total 
FROM subscriptions 
WHERE status = 'A' 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(zip, 1, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY` expressions, pick your favourite string functions to do the job from
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

```
SELECT zip, COUNT(id) AS total FROM subscriptions
WHERE status = 'A'
GROUP BY LEFT( zip, 5 );
```